# SQL Loader is not inserting data when NULL

Tags: oracle, sql-loader

I have the following table:

```
Name                                      Null?    Type
----------------------------------------- -------- ----------------------------
NAME                                               VARCHAR2(230)
TEST                                               VARCHAR2(230)
ID6                                                VARCHAR2(230)
ID4                                                VARCHAR2(230)
ID1                                                VARCHAR2(230)
ID2                                                VARCHAR2(230)
ID3                                                VARCHAR2(230)
ID5                                                VARCHAR2(230)
ID                                                 NUMBER(38)
```

Case 1:

Now I try to insert data through `sqlldr`. It loads data when values are provided for all of the columns, as follows:

```
a,b,c,d,e,f,g,1
a,b,c,d,e,f,g,1
a,b,c,d,e,f,g,1
a,b,c,d,e,f,g,1
a,b,c,d,e,f,g,1
```

Case 2:

when I try to load data like so:

```
a,,,,,,,
```

data is not loaded.

I also tried using this way:

```
a,NULL,NULL,NULL,NULL,NULL,NULL,NULL,NULL
```

but got the message:

> Commit point reached - logical record count 1

When I take count on that table, it remains 0.

Can anyone help me load the data from case 2?

My contol file:

```
LOAD DATA INFILE 'temp.txt' 
BADFILE 'temp_log.txt' 
INTO TABLE a 
FIELDS TERMINATED BY "," (
name,
test,
id6,
id4,
id1,
id2,
id3,
id5,
id)
```

Comment: Can you post ur control file please?

Comment: LOAD DATA
INFILE 'temp.txt'
BADFILE 'temp_log.txt'
INTO TABLE a
FIELDS TERMINATED BY  ","
(name,test,id6,id4,id1,id2,id3,id5,id)

Comment: What does the log file say? (Not the `badfile`, that wil just show the skipped record; the actual `.log`)

Comment: where can i find that log file.. same folder as control.ctl file??

Comment: By default it has the same name as the control file, but with a `.log` extension instead of `.ctl`. And yes, in the same directory.

Comment: you need a comma after the last value, or add trailing null colls to the ctl file

Answer (score 0):

try the following code
i had tried it.its working

a sample data is taken for test in temp.txt

```
a,,,,,,,
```

use "***trailing nullcols***" for inserting null data in the table

```
LOAD DATA 
INFILE 'temp.txt' 
BADFILE 'temp_log.txt' 
INTO TABLE a 
FIELDS TERMINATED BY "," 
trailing nullcols
(name,
test,
id6,
id4,
id1,
id2,
id3,
id5,
id)
```

writing the control file.Let the control file is saved with "***samp.ctl***" and the data file is saved as temp.txt.

execute the file by using the following command in the command prompt
syntax will be

***sqlldr username/password@database control=control_path_file log=log_path_file***

```
sqlldr abc/abc@orcl123 control=samp.ctl log=log_samp.log
```

the result will be ***Commit point reached - logical record count 1***